# add attributes from separate rows that have a common attribute

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to add together two integers from two rows in a table that have a common attribute. Here is the table:

```
=> select * from hello;
            exname            | location  | numitems
------------------------------+-----------+----------
 Notes                        | Gallery B |       10
 Notes to Coins               | Gallery C |       16
 Silver Dollars               | Gallery A |        9
 Silver Dollars               | Gallery D |        2
(4 rows)
```

I'm trying to query the table to create a result that has the two rows with exname = 'Silver Dollars' combined together with numitems summed up for just those two rows.

I'm trying to create a query that has this result:

```
            exname            | numitems
------------------------------+----------
 Notes                        |       10
 Notes to Coins               |       16
 Silver Dollars               |       11
(3 rows)
```

Notice that the 9 and 2 have been summed up to 11. How do I do this?

Comment: There are many answers about summing with a group in stack overflow. https://www.google.com.au/search?q=sum+group+sql+stackoverflow&oq=sum+group+sql+stackoverflow&aqs=chrome..69i57.13432j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=sum+group+sql+stack+overflow

Comment: Thanks, Keith John Hutchison! I guess I just didn't know the words to google.

Answer (score 1):

This would work.

```
select exname, sum(numitems) numitems 
from hello
group by exname ;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
select exname, sum(numitems)as numitems 
from hello
group by exname
```